# Export order item number in dataset

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a join of two tables, order and order items in MySQL. I want to add a column with item number in the order, like this:

| OrderItemNr. | Order ID | otherData | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | some data | ... |
| 1 | 124 | some data | .... |
| 2 | 123 | some data | .... |
| 3 | 124 | some data |  |
| 1 | 125 | some data |  |
| 2 | 125 | some data |  |

Is this possible directly in MySQL or needs some adjusments? Can do this in php for instance, but I wonder is possible directly on the db server. Of course, OrdeItemNumber is not a field in the database.

Comment: It's not clear why orderid appears multiple times with different counts. Please clarify by adding sample data from both tables which produces the published desired outcome.

Comment: Each order has different number of items. For instance, Order 123 has 1 item, order 124 has 3, order 125 has 2. For each order I need to list itemnumber (1, 2, 3...). Rest of the data in the row is irrelevant, i only need to put in there the column with itemnumber. Can't do that on item insert as user might add/delete, so the item nr. 1 in an order might actually have been item 5, but user deleted previous 4. and the added 3 more. in php I could do:
$count=0;
While ($row2=ezpub_fetch_array($result2)){
 $count=$count+1;
...
I need similar for MySQL